# Oracle SQL Insert -ve Infinity in Float Datatype

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there any way to insert negative Infinity in a column of FLOAT Datatype in Oracle DB.

Answer (score 2):

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( value BINARY_FLOAT );
```

Then you can use the [`BINARY_FLOAT_INFINITY` literal](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51047):

```sql
INSERT INTO test_data ( value ) VALUES ( binary_float_infinity );
```

And, if you want negative infinity, just prepend it with a minus sign:

```sql
INSERT INTO test_data ( value ) VALUES ( -binary_float_infinity );
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM test_data;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | VALUE |
> | :---- |
> | Inf   |
> | -Inf  |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d16a47e7b7d54dd13074b1494fd5e1ed)*

---

**Update**

> The data type is `FLOAT`

The ANSI `FLOAT` data type is just an alias for Oracle's `NUMBER` data type.

From the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28285/sqlqr06.htm#CHDBBHHE):

> `FLOAT [(p)]` - A subtype of the `NUMBER` datatype having precision `p`. A `FLOAT` value is represented internally as `NUMBER`. The precision `p` can range from 1 to 126 binary digits. A `FLOAT` value requires from 1 to 22 bytes.

It may be technically possible to put infinity into a `FLOAT` data type (particularly if you use an external application that bypasses the normal validation methods). One such example is to use `DBMS_STATS.CONVERT_RAW_VALUE`:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION negative_infinity RETURN FLOAT
IS
  value FLOAT;
BEGIN
  DBMS_STATS.CONVERT_RAW_VALUE(
    UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW( CHR(255)||CHR(101)),
    value
  );
  RETURN value;
END;
/
```

Then you can do:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data2( value FLOAT );
INSERT INTO test_data2 ( value ) VALUES ( negative_infinity() );
```

But that does not mean that the value is supported:

```sql
SELECT SUM(value) FROM test_data2;
```

Gives:

> ```
> ORA-01426: numeric overflow
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f3c6cda5c0d09f23d5e1387c8362e6a3)*

If you want to support infinity then use the data type that supports it `BINARY_FLOAT` or `BINARY_DOUBLE`; don't try to get the values into a `FLOAT` or `NUMBER` data type where they can theoretically o if you bypass the normal validation methods but aren't actually supported.

Comment: The datatype is FLOAT

Comment: @manitejavarma Oracle has two ["float" data types](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1834): `BINARY_FLOAT` and `BINARY_DOUBLE`. I've given you can example for `BINARY_FLOAT`. If you are ust using a `FLOAT` then that is just an alias to the `NUMBER` data type and you aren't using a float at all and it can't handle infinity.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to insert negative Infinity in a column of FLOAT Datatype in Oracle DB.

No, not in the standard Oracle way of inserting the data in SQL or PL/SQL.

On **19c** database:

```
select banner from v$version;

BANNER                                                                          
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
```

**FLOAT** doesn't support infinity:

```
create table float_infinity_test (id float);  
insert into float_infinity_test values (1/0f);

Error report -
ORA-01426: numeric overflow
```

whereas, **BINARY_FLOAT** does:

```
create table bin_float_test as (select 1/0f as id from dual); 
desc bin_float_test;

Name Null? Type         
---- ----- ------------ 
ID         BINARY_FLOAT
```

Comment: 18c does support it and there are values in my column. I want to replicate them.

Comment: @manitejavarma I gave the demo on 19c database. In the standard Oracle way it is not possible in SQL or PL/SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The Integer and float supports infinity it is only that SQL and PLSQL engine of Oracle doesn't support.You can bypass the same using the below function

```
 CREATE OR replace FUNCTION Bypass_number_validation(v1 IN NUMBER,
                                                        v2 IN NUMBER)
    RETURN FLOAT
    IS
      vnum FLOAT;
    BEGIN
        dbms_stats.Convert_raw_value(utl_raw.Cast_to_raw(Chr(v1)
                                                         ||Chr(v2)), vnum);

        RETURN vnum;
    END; 


    create table t1p( id float);


   insert into t1p values(bypass_number_validation(255,101));

   select * from t1p;

    ID

  -Infinity
```

You can select the column using the literal BINARY_FLOAT_INFINITY like below

```
 select * from t1p where id= -BINARY_FLOAT_INFINITY;
```

If you want to do any aggregation in that table just exclude the infinity number

```
 select sum(id) from t1p where id <> -BINARY_FLOAT_INFINITY;
```

If there is a constraint for you to use FLOAT and not BINARY FLOAT,you can achieve the same results for aggregation as below

```
   SELECT SUM (id)
    FROM   (SELECT ( id ) id
            FROM   t1p
            WHERE  ( id <> -binary_float_infinity
                     AND id <> binary_float_infinity )
            UNION ALL
            SELECT ( -binary_float_infinity )
            FROM   t1p
            WHERE  id = -binary_float_infinity
            UNION ALL
            SELECT ( binary_float_infinity )
            FROM   t1p
            WHERE  id = binary_float_infinity);
```

Comment: And it might screw up the table data and won't allow normal SQL aggregation etc.

Comment: As per this link Oracle allows it from java and external language ,only SQL and PLSQL engine will not support it https://community.oracle.com/thread/3916011?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Java itself doesn't support infinity for integers, it uses double class NaN concept. And topic has nothing to do with Java or OCI. Standard Oracle method doesn't allow infinity to insert into number or float. Period.